# Why it's different?

Tags: php, date

```
echo date("w",strtotime(date("Y-m-d")));
echo date("w",strtotime(date("Y年m月d日")));
```

Save it as utf8.You'll see the second is bigger than the first one.

Comment: Okaaaay.. and where exatly is the question? In the topic, no?

Comment: Hm. I see strange artefacts on the second line - the "m" and "d" look very different from those on the first line, are you sure that those are the ASCII m and d, and not some similar Unicode symbol? (could be a font issue though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mask,

most probably because [strtotime](http://fr.php.net/strtotime) is not able to parse properly the japanese formated date.

In my opinion, by reading the documentation it would accept date formated with `-` but that's not explicitly said.

trying `var_dump(strtotime(date("Y年m月d日"));` give `false` so like in the documentation the `strtotime` seems to fail to parse it.

so date apply on `false` which don't give the same result.

Comment: Seems only you got what I mean.But can you verify it?

Comment: I think like pointed out other person it might something to do with the double byte. but really no way to check that apart inspecting the php source code

Comment: @Mask, just try echo strtotime( date("Y年m月d日") );

Answer (score 2):

If by "bigger" you mean "it uses more bytes", it's beacause UTF8 is an encoding with variable character size. A - character will be encoded with one single byte, while 年 will be encoded with at least two. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8

Comment: and ? what is has to do with the w, day of the week being different?

Comment: He just said "second is bigger". I'm not sure what he meant so I took a possible interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that strtotime is expection a valid date in US format ( readyble here http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php )

to solve this you could use the function strftime

```
    echo date("w",strftime(date("Y年m月d日")));
    echo date("w",strftime(date("Y-m-d")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Asian characters take up 2 or more bytes when represented in UTF-8, while dashes only take one byte.